# WhatsApp backup shrinks in size for no apparent reason

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger

AFAIK, there were never `msgstore.db.crypt14` incremental backups in WhatsApp message file backup design strategy. In other words, every day, WhatsApp leaves a 1.1GB file in `/sdcard/WhatsApp/databases`. Now, I know I did not delete any messages in bulk; in fact, none. What I observed is that the database backup size has shrunk a tad bit.

[image]

What can explain this? Could any of the following be happening to account for the screenshot?

- WhatsApp now refuses to back up messages past a certain time frame, e.g. oldest message will be `today() - 365*x`.
- Compression has changed - well, it did from `crypt12` to `crypt14`, but we are still at `crypt14`.
- There is some incremental approach in play and not all days get full backups.

P.S. My internal storage WhatsApp partition is getting full, so I have written a batch script that moves `msgstore.db.crypt14` files from their default location to another. What you see is in the latter directory.